# Issue with SHAP dependency plots: TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Explanation which has no callable conjugate method

Tags: python, numpy, xgboost, shap

I am attempting to the use the SHAP python library on an XGBoost model I built for binary classification on tabular data.
While attempting to generate dependency plots in particular, I get the following error.

`TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Explanation which has no callable conjugate method`

Here is the full traceback:

https://pastebin.com/u3imDXir

My code for the SHAP analysis seems fairly basic and I am able to generate beeswarm plots with no trouble.

```
import shap

explainer = shap.Explainer(model, X_train)
shap_values = explainer(X_train)

max_display = 20

shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_train, max_display=max_display, color_bar=False, show=False)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(5, 7)
plt.colorbar(label='feature value', ticks=[], fraction=0.03, pad=0.04)
plt.title = "SHAP beeswarm summary plot"
plt.savefig(('../reports/figures/01_successbutdialysisDurReversed/all_Data_plotted/summary_plot_limFeatures_' + str(max_display) + '.png'), dpi=600, bbox_inches='tight')`
```

It is when I attempt to make the dependence_plot that I start to get the errors.

```
shap.dependence_plot("iv_total", shap_values, X_train)
plt.show()
```

I have thus far attempted to wipe my virtualenv and install the latest anaconda distributions for major packages, on Python 3.10. If it is of relevance, I am using an M1 Mac. I would appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Please [reprex]

Answer (score 1):

Try either

```
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_train)
```

or

```
shap.dependence_plot("iv_total", shap_values.values, X_train)
```